# HTML parts locating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract each row individually to eventually create a dataframe to export them into a csv. I can't locate the individual parts of the html.

I can find and save the entire content (although I can only seem to save this on a loop so the pages appear hundreds of times), but I can't find any html parts nested beneath this. My code is as follows, trying to find the first row:

```
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'view-content'})

    for infos in content:
        try:
            data = infos.find('div', {'class': 'type type_18'}).text
        except:
            print("None found")

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace(': ','')

df[['type','rrr']] = df['rrr'].str.split("|",expand=True)

df.to_csv (r'savehere.csv', index = False, header = True)
```

This code just prints "None found" because, I assume, it hasn't found anything else to print. I don't know if I am not finding the right html part or what.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

###### What happens?

Main issue here is that `content = soup.find('div', {'class': 'view-content'})` is no `ResultSet` and contains only a single element. Thats why your second loop only iterates once.

Also Caused by this behavior you will swap from `beautifoulsoup` method `find()` to python string method `find()` and these two are operating in a different way - Without `try/except` you will see the what is going on, it try to find a string:

```
for x in soup.find('div', {'class': 'view-content'}):
    print(x.find('div'))
```

Output

```
...
-1
<div class="views-field views-field-title-1"> <span class="views-label views-label-title-1">RRR: </span> <span class="field-content"><div class="type type_18">Eleemosynary grant</div>2256</span> </div>
...
```

---

###### How to fix?

Select your elements more specific in this case the `views-row`:

```
sections = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'views-row'})
```

While you iterate each section you could select expected value:

```
sections = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'views-row'})

for section in sections:
    print(section.select_one('div[class*="type_"]').text)
```

###### Example

Is scraping all the information and creates `DataFrame`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

data = []
website = #link here#
    

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    sections = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'views-row'})

    for section in sections:
        d = {}
        for row in section.select('div.views-field'):
            d[row.span.text] = row.select_one('span:nth-of-type(2)').get_text('|',strip=True)
        data.append(d)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

### replacing : in header and set all to lower case
df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().str.replace(': ','')
```

...

Answer (score 2):

I think that You wanted to make pagination using `for loop and range` method and to grab  `RRR` value.I've done the next pages meaning pagination in long url.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = #insert url#
data=[]
for page in range(1,7):
    req=requests.get(url.format(page=page))

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content,'lxml')
    
    for r in soup.select('[class="views-field views-field-title-1"] span:nth-child(2)'):

        rr=list(r.stripped_strings)[-1]
        #print(rr)
        
        data.append(rr)


df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['RRR'])
print(df)
#df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

**Output:**

List